# React component can't find function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

My application has a component that creates a navigation bar at the top of certain pages. I want to show the 'logout' button ONLY if the user is currently logged in (there's a token stored in localStorage).

When the code below is run, the browser gives me the following error:

*ReferenceError: Can't find variable: showLogout*

```
import React from 'react'
import NavHelper from './components/nav-helper'

export default React.createClass({
  render () {
    return(
      <NavHelper>
        <nav className='top-nav top-nav-light cf' role='navigation'>
          <input id='menu-toggle' className='menu-toggle' type='checkbox'/>
          <label htmlFor='menu-toggle'>Menu</label>
            <ul className='list-unstyled list-inline cf'>
              <li><a href="/home">Website</a></li>
              <li><a href='/languages'>Languages</a></li>
              <li><a href='/topics'>Topics</a></li>
              //==========================
              {window.localStorage.token ? showLogout() : null}
              //==========================
              <li className='pull-right'><a href='/saved'>Saved</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div className='container'>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </NavHelper>

    )
  },
  showLogout() {
    return (<li className='pull-right'><a href='/logout'>Logout</a></li>)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a class you should refer to interior functions like this:  `this.showLogout()`

Comment: Doh. I swear I tried that and it didn't work. But after trying again, it's now working. Thank you.